# How can I extract info between a certain text from a string only if the text in previous line matches a item from a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to extract text between  certain keywords in a string only if the previous line matches an item from a different list.

I have a broken xml file that I am reading as a string (which is the only way I have to do it) and then separating the items using regex which has worked perfectly so far.
Now within each of the items in a list I have got multiple `<xyz>foo</xyz>` tags preceded by an `<abc>GH1234</abc>` tag from which I want to be able to extract `foo` only if `GH1234` matches an item in a list bar.

```
matches = re.findall(r'<abc>(.*)<\/abc>', text)
```

I expect the output to be only `foo` but I am getting all the `foo1,foo2,foo3` because of the presence of multiple `<abc>` tags within the text which is why I want this condition to be applied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the first match only use `re.search(regex, string).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`matches = re.findall(r'<abc>(bar1|bar2|bar3)<\/abc><xyz>(.*?)<\/xyz>', text)`

In the regex I enumerated the elements from your list `bar`: `bar1`, `bar2`, `bar3` .
The regex you wrote will take everything between the first `abc` tag and the last `xyz` tag.

Even with my regex, there will be a problem in the following case :

`<abc>CD1234</abc>
<abc>EF1234</abc>
<xyz>foo</xyz>`

I hope this would be useful.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned the list containing ````GH1234```` has at least 150 elements so would be difficult to include them all in the regex itself

Comment: You cannot make a regex for the elements in that list ?

Comment: Yes, that idea worked after spending a few hours on the regex for the elements in the last. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am glad to hear that! If you think the answer helped you, please vote for it.